# How to update data in index.html.erb in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create one app about product that has `name`, `price` and `description`. In **index.html.erb**, I wanna add textbox to each of them and click edit link can edit don't need go to /products/id/edit.

How can I edit the product data?

```
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <form action="/products/<%= product.id %>" class="edit_person_<%= product.id %>" id="edit_person_<%= product.id %>" method="post">
          <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
          <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="NrOp5bsjoLRuK8IW5+dQEYjKGUJDe7TQoZVvq95Wteg=" />
          <td><input id="product_name" name="product[name]" type="text" value="<%= product.name %>" /><br /></td>
          <td><input id="product_price" name="product[price]" type="text" value="<%= product.price %>" /><br /></td>
          <td><input id="product_descr" name="product[descr]" type="text" value="<%= product.descr %>" /><br /></td>
          <td><input name="commit<%= product.id %>" type="submit" value="edit" /></td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: you can do it by using AJAX

Comment: may you show me how to use AJAX?

Comment: You need to follow CRUD. If you want to edit your data, you need to do it in your `edit.html.erb`.

Comment: I wanna edit in index.html.erb . if you know solution please help me

Answer (score -1):

You need to use AJAX if you want to update your data without reloading the **edit.html.erb** file. Below, I'm gonna show it how to this for one field, rest you can assume yourself.

```
<input id="product_price" name="product[price]" type="text" value="<%= product.price %>" />
```

In your **js.erb** file, you can write:

```
$("#product_price").focusout(function() {
    var productPrice = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/products/<%= product.id %>/edit",
        type: "POST",
        data: { product_price: productPrice}, // same way, other attributes
        success: function() {
            console.log("The result successfully came back from ther server.");
            // Now, here you can show a notice to the user that he has successfully update the record without reloading the page.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Can you show me your code?